# String Array Custom Property

Tags: android, android-xml, android-resources

I've a string array in array.xml:

```
<string-array name="stringList">
    <item indent="true">Item1</item>
    <item indent="false">Item2</item>
    <item indent="false">Item3</item>
    <item indent="true">Item4</item>
</string-array>
```

As you've noticed, I need to declare a custom properties for the string (indent). My aim is to generate an HashMap with key = "ItemX" and value = "true/false". Is it possibile to do that in android? Any smarter way? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have double "" after the Boolean for the Item 2 to 4 ?

Answer (score 2):

Just use 2 arrays :)

```
<string-array name="keys">
    <item>Item1</item>
    <item>Item2</item>
    <item>Item3</item>
    <item>Item4</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="values">
    <item>true</item>
    <item>true</item>
    <item>false</item>
    <item>false</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Mh, k =) just looking for something more compact.

Comment: Found it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013655/creating-hashmap-map-from-xml-resources

Comment: splitting values is another simple solution