# Is (null != key) the same as (key != null)

Tags: java, android, xmlpullparser

I have a `XmlPullParser` and to set it up I found something useful via google here on StackOverflow [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15024231/3092455)

As I looked through it, I found the line `if (null != key)` and I am a bit confused because I only know the expression `(key != null)`.

Where is the difference or is it just the same?

Comment: This is exactly the same.

Comment: They are the same, most people like to read things left to right with the object of the statement on the left but not everyone does it.

Comment: when used with `==`, it also helps prevent typing `if(key = null)` since you can't make an assignment to `null`

Comment: a != b and b != a is always same, answer will not change due to null

Comment: @kelmer no proper IDE will allow this (and no compiler either), because of incompatible types for the `if` condition.

Comment: so nothing magic behind :) Just didn't want to implement something I'm not really sure of

Comment: @Smutje if key is an object then it *can* always be assigned to null

Comment: @kelmer that was very nicely put- "since you can't make an assignment to null". 
 i think "!=" means we are reading it from left to right :) , and it doesn't sound that correct when we are checking whether "null" is not equal to some value

Comment: But only if `key = null` results in a boolean expression and therefore only if `key` is of `Boolean` type.

Comment: @kelmer you cannot write if(key=null) because if expects a boolean parameter. you will get compile time error

Comment: @royB You're right there. I guess this issue arises with checks like `key == 2`, and then the null check with null to the left comes as you get used to that syntax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoiding "!= null" statements in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java)

Comment: in response to the duplicate flag: mine and your flagged question have nothing in common. my question has nothing to do with avoiding, but with understanding the possible difference, that, like I learned now is no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same.

The coding style comes from C/C++ where mistakes like

```
if (variable = value)
```

are easy to write when

```
if (variable == value)
```

was meant. At most a compiler warning is emitted. By consistently writing the [r-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_%28computer_science%29) first, unintended assignments are avoided since attempting to assign to a r-value is a compile-time error.

Comment: (Old question, came up in Close Votes review. Voted to Leave Open.)