# Subitems for items in array and get their data to a variable and change item in array

Tags: java, android

I have created this in an activity:

```
protected void onClickSunSea(View v) {
    persons = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPerson);
    days = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDays);
    String p = persons.getText().toString();
    String d = days.getText().toString();
    String [] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sunsea);
    Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    myintent.putExtra("PERSONS", p);
    myintent.putExtra("DAYS", d);
    myintent.putExtra("PLACES",array);
    startActivity(myintent);
}
```

To send to this activity:

```
String person = getIntent().getStringExtra("PERSONS");
    String day = getIntent().getStringExtra("DAYS");

    TextView txtPerson = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewPersons);
    txtPerson.setText("Persons travelling: " + person);
    TextView txtDay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewDays);
    txtDay.setText("Days of traveling: " + day);

    String[] arrayCityBreak = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("PLACES");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterCityBreak = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayCityBreak);
    ListView myview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstView);
    myview.setAdapter(adapterCityBreak);
```

I have made these arrays in strings.xml:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Assignment</string>

<array name="citybreak">
    <item>Barcelona, Spain</item>
    <item>Berlin, Germany</item>
    <item>Copenhagen, Denmark</item>
    <item>Gothenburg, Sweden</item>
    <item>Milan, Italy</item>
</array>

<array name="sunsea">
    <item>Alicante, Spain</item>
    <item>Antalya, Turkey</item>
    <item>Athens, Greece</item>
    <item>Florida, USA</item>
    <item>Gran Canaria, Spain</item>
</array>

<array name="skisnow">
    <item>Kiruna, Sweden</item>
    <item>Trondheim, Norway</item>
    <item>Salzburg, Austria</item>
    <item>Kittila, Finland</item>
    <item>Ivalo, Finland</item>
</array>
```

I want to insert a subitem with a price inside it, for example:
**Barcelona, Spain**
200
And then get that "200" value in a variable and change it, and then put it back in the array to write it out with the new value + some text before it. Like this:
**Barcelona, Spain**
the cost for 2 persons is 400 
Can anyone help me with that?
Hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should use some kind of [Map](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html) for this data, so you'll be able to have a pair where city name will be a key and the price will be a value. The bad news is that you can't save Map in the resources. But you can "emulate" it, for example use "|" as a separator:

```
<array name="citybreak">
 <item>Barcelona, Spain|200</item>
 <item>Berlin, Germany|300</item>
 <item>Copenhagen, Denmark|250</item>
 <item>Gothenburg, Sweden|500</item>
 <item>Milan, Italy|700</item>
</array>
```

Then you can parse these strings and create a Map from it. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15030150/1894868) answer as an example. When you'll have a Map, you can pass it to your second activity, modify prices there and then send it back with new prices.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that

Comment: I wont make the change permanent, it is just for using the value to calculate it and insert the new value, but not save it, just for showcase, if you understood

Comment: Sure, "can't save Map in the resources" - I mean you can't put it to resources like you've done with String's array