# Using Java, how can I reference a non-standard type xml object in the Android architecture?

Tags: java, android, xml, hashmap

I've just begun learning to create Android apps, and I'm struggling with what seems like a very elementary problem.

I'm trying to create a HashMap which is loaded from an XML. However, I'm unable to figure out what the resource ID for a Map stored this way would be. I've used the solution to this problem: [Creating hashmap/map from XML resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013655/creating-hashmap-map-from-xml-resources)
.

The issue I'm facing is how exactly to structure the res folder and how to reference my data in that res folder.

Here's what I currently have:

**Resource Parser[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013655/creating-hashmap-map-from-xml-resources):**

```
public class ResourceUtils {
    public static Map<String,String> getHashMapResource(Context c, int hashMapResId) {
        Map<String,String> map = null;
        XmlResourceParser parser = c.getResources().getXml(hashMapResId);

        String key = null, value = null;

        ...

        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

**[My res/xml/map.xml file looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIR3W.png)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<map name = "testMap" linked="true">
    <entry key="key1">value1</entry>
    <entry key="key2">value2</entry>
    <entry key="key3">value3</entry>
</map>
```

So to get hold of the Map, I need to correctly enter the resource ID into my call to getHashMapResource, but I can't find how to do that! I've tried:

- `R.string.map`
- `R.map.testMap`
- `R.xml.map`
- `R.xml.testMap`

I'm out of ideas. I'm sure the problem is trivial to someone who knows this, but I couldn't find anything helpful around the place. Thanks :)

Comment: Resource xml file should have `<resources>` tag as root. Look at string resource file https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.plumtestongo.sample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.XmlResourceParser;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



     Map<String,String>  map = getHashMapResource(this,R.xml.map);
        Log.i("Hello",map.toString());
    }




    public  Map<String,String> getHashMapResource(Context c, int hashMapResId) {
        Map<String,String> map = null;
        XmlResourceParser parser = c.getResources().getXml(hashMapResId);

        String key = null, value = null;



        try {
            int eventType = parser.getEventType();

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                    Log.d("utils","Start document");
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if (parser.getName().equals("map")) {
                        boolean isLinked = parser.getAttributeBooleanValue(null, "linked", false);

                        map = isLinked ? new LinkedHashMap<String, String>() : new HashMap<String, String>();
                    } else if (parser.getName().equals("entry")) {
                        key = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "key");

                        if (null == key) {
                            parser.close();
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    if (parser.getName().equals("entry")) {
                        map.put(key, value);

                        key = null;
                        value = null;
                    }
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                    if (null != key) {
                        value = parser.getText();
                    }
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return map;
}

}
```

I tested this code it works. All you need is use R.xml.map .